# How do i select the 1st and then every 4th row in a html-table with nth-child()-selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Ok, math isn't my strong side, I admit it.

All I want to do is to select the first, 5th, 9th, 13th, 17th etc row in a html-table. Can anybody with better math-skills point me in the right directionor perhaps supply a "nth-child-for-dummies" guide?

I tried nth-child(1n+4) (which selects the 4th row and everyone after), and i also tried nth-child(0n+4) which selects the fourth row and nothing after that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shoulb be something like

```
tr:nth-child(4n+1) {
  declarations
}
```

Comment: So that 
n = 0 ==> 4 * 0 + 1 = 1
n = 1 ==> 4 * 1 + 1 = 5
n = 2 ==> 4 * 2 + 1 = 9
ans so on...

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Think i understand the automaical workings behind it now...