# Set Different Color for every 5 row in php

Tags: php

```
@php $count = 1 ; @endphp
                            @for($i = 0; $i <= 99; $i++)
                                @php
                                    if($count % 6 == 0){
                                        $css = 'honeydew';
                                    }else{
                                        $css = 'aliceblue';
                                    }
                                    
                                $count++;
                                @endphp
                                <tr class="allrow {{$css}}" id="row_{{$i}}">
                                    <td width="20%">
                                    <select class="form-control select2 firstname v1" id="name1_{{$i}}" name="name[]" style="width: 100%;">
                                        
                                    </select></td>
                                    <td width="20%"><input type="number" name="winlose[]" id="amt1_{{$i}}" class="form-control first" value="0.00"></td>
                                    {{-- <td width="20%"><select class="form-control select2 secondname v1" id="name2_{{$key}}" name="name2[]"></select></td>
                                    <td width="20%"><input type="number" name="winlose[]" id="amt2_{{$key}}" class="form-control second"></td> --}}
                                    <td width="20%"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove">-</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            @endfor
```

[image]

Question: Trying to give 2 different colors which are honeydew and aliceblue for every 5 rows in the loop in PHP, How can I implement it? For example, the first 5 rows will be honeydew, then 5-10 rows will be aliceblue. It will respectively.

Comment: Minor improvement: you do not really need $count, you can use $i for that

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? How is this related to Laravel?

Comment: Additionally: have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable about how to run a loop with less variables - or why do you need a `$count` variable **and** `$i`? Why not use a `@foreach` and `$loop->index`?

Comment: @NicoHaase the code is there, and its blade, so don't see the problem

Comment: Although this question has been already answered: the cleanest approach would have been to use css. [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068522/how-do-i-select-the-1st-and-then-every-4th-row-in-a-html-table-with-nth-child) shows how you can select every 4th row, using this you could select 5 rows every 10th row. (tr:nth-child(10n+0), tr:nth-child(10n+1), ..., tr:nth-child(10n+4))

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal it's fine to post this as an additional answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the $css value and changing it every 5 records:

```
@php $count = 1; $css = 'honeydew'; @endphp
                            @for($i = 0; $i <= 99; $i++)
                                @php
                                    if($count % 6 == 0){
                                        $css = ($css === 'honeydew' ) ? 'aliceblue' : 'honeydew';
                                    }
                                    
                                $count++;
                                @endphp
                                <tr class="allrow {{$css}}" id="row_{{$i}}">
                                    <td width="20%">
                                    <select class="form-control select2 firstname v1" id="name1_{{$i}}" name="name[]" style="width: 100%;">
                                        
                                    </select></td>
                                    <td width="20%"><input type="number" name="winlose[]" id="amt1_{{$i}}" class="form-control first" value="0.00"></td>
                                    {{-- <td width="20%"><select class="form-control select2 secondname v1" id="name2_{{$key}}" name="name2[]"></select></td>
                                    <td width="20%"><input type="number" name="winlose[]" id="amt2_{{$key}}" class="form-control second"></td> --}}
                                    <td width="20%"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove">-</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            @endfor
```

Comment: you could do away with `$count` and just use `$i`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone see my comment on the question :-)

Answer (score -1):

Here's a basic example in PHP using regex.  Basically, it will check if the number ends with 0-4 and set CSS to honeydew, if not set to aliceblue.

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 99; $i++) {

    if (preg_match('/[0-4]$/', $i)) {
        $css = 'honeydew';
    } else {
        $css = 'aliceblue';
    }
    echo $css . PHP_EOL;
}
```